# Re-fitting model with partial data results lower accuracy than fitting model with full data

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

My dataset is large and cannot fit into RAM. My hypothesis is to divide the dataset into large chunks and train the model iteratively and see similar accuracy results as non-divided dataset (as described in [#107](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/107)). So, I tested it in two steps with a sample set of 146244 elements.

- First, try splitting the data into three chunks (50000, 50000 and 46244) and fit the model with each chunk. To be on the safe side, I load the model saved in the previous iteration.
- Second try fitting the model with full data (146244 elements).

Here's the code for creating and fitting the model:

```html
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
 model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

 optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0001)
 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
           loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
           metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.save(top_model_path)

 for train_data, train_labels in hdf5_generator('D:/_g/kaggle/cdisco/files/features_xception_1_100_90x90_tr1.hdf5', 'train', train_labels):
  model = load_model(top_model_path)
  model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=2, batch_size=batch_size)
  model.save(top_model_path)
  (eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate(validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
  print("Accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(eval_accuracy * 100))
  print("Loss: {}\n".format(eval_loss))
```

And, here is the code for the generator:

```html
def hdf5_generator(file_name, dataset, labels):
 hf = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
 i = 0
 batch_size = 50000
 while 1:
  start = i * batch_size
  end = ((i + 1) * batch_size)
  print("start: %d -- end: %d" % (start, end))
  yield (hf[dataset][start:end], labels[start:end])
  if end >= len(hf[dataset]): break
  i += 1
```

First try with chunked data results in unstable accuracy between steps (22,90%, 59,93%, 51,17%):

```html
start: 0 -- end: 50000
Epoch 1/2
50000/50000 [==============================] - 39s - loss: 2.4969 - acc: 0.5143
Epoch 2/2
50000/50000 [==============================] - 38s - loss: 1.5667 - acc: 0.6201
16156/16156 [==============================] - 33s
Accuracy: 22.90%
Loss: 5.976185762991436

start: 50000 -- end: 100000
Epoch 1/2
50000/50000 [==============================] - 38s - loss: 1.3759 - acc: 0.7211
Epoch 2/2
50000/50000 [==============================] - 39s - loss: 0.5446 - acc: 0.8621
16156/16156 [==============================] - 34s
Accuracy: 59.93%
Loss: 2.540657121840312

start: 100000 -- end: 150000
Epoch 1/2
46244/46244 [==============================] - 36s - loss: 0.2640 - acc: 0.9531
Epoch 2/2
46244/46244 [==============================] - 36s - loss: 0.1283 - acc: 0.9672
16156/16156 [==============================] - 34s
Accuracy: 51.17%
Loss: 3.8107337748964336
```

Second try (with batch_size=146244 in hdf5_generator) results in 77.49% accuracy:

```html
start: 0 -- end: 146244
Epoch 1/2
146244/146244 [==============================] - 112s - loss: 1.8089 - acc: 0.6123
Epoch 2/2
146244/146244 [==============================] - 113s - loss: 1.0966 - acc: 0.7265
16156/16156 [==============================] - 39s
Accuracy: 77.49%
Loss: 0.8401890944788202
```

I expected to see similar accuracy results. However, results were different and first results seems like model loses parameters between iterations. How can I get results with chunked dataset with re-fitting similar to single fitting with full data?

I tried using HDF5Matrix, but it resulted in very low performance.

Comment: why don't you use `model.fit_generator`?

Comment: `model.fit_generator` is too slow to train to an acceptable accuracy. maybe it's because I'm reading from hdf5. do you know how to make it run faster?

Comment: Have you tried to run this experiment several times? Is this common behviour?

Comment: yes, I ran the experiment many times. the results are quite similar to the ones I shared. It is common behaviour.